# Como usar o broken_barh do pyplot, usando datas? Pois desejo montar um gráfico de gantt

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from math import floor
    
    def tamanho(lista):
        return floor(len(lista)/2)
    
    rangex = [[(0,1.5)], [(1.5,3)], [(3,3)]]
    rangey = [(n, -.5) for n in range(tamanho(rangex),-tamanho(rangex) - 1,-1)]
    color = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']
    
    for charts in range(len(rangex)):
        plt.broken_barh(rangex[charts], rangey[charts], facecolor=color[charts])
```

A partir desse código, que possui um output como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de poder inserir datas, alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso, usando o `broken_barh`?

Acabei não falando, mas planejo que as datas estejam em formato `%d/%m/%Y`

Comment: Acabei não falando, mas planejo que as datas estejam em formato %d/%m/%Y

Comment: Já viu este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425908/matplotlib-how-to-use-timestamps-with-broken-barh)?

Comment: Vi agora @PauloMarques, obrigado!